# I have two wcf service running and getting error posting 900KB file

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, c#-4.0, iis

I am getting following exception trying to post xml of around 1MB.

> - ex  {"RequestEntityTooLarge (413) is not one of the following: OK (200), Created (201), Accepted (202), NonAuthoritativeInformation
>     (203), NoContent (204), ResetContent (205), PartialContent
>     (206)"}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

I have couple of wcf configured under one wcf project.. so how do I configure so I can run both service which can accept 1MB  or even bigger xml post.. Thanks (what's the max size limit)..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a big guess shot since there's absolutely no detail about your bindings or actual exception message. Check out your bindings and make sure the `maxReceivedMessageSize` is not set to the default, the default is 65,536 bytes (64 KB). So make sure it is set to something big...

```
<binding maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304">
```

The example above is set to 4,194,304 bytes (4 MB)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.95).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize%28v=vs.95%29.ASPX)

Answer (score 0):

max size limit is 2147483647 bytes .

You should set `maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"` to increase message size also consider having sendTimeout="00:10:00" which is default 1 minute.

Try increasing message size like(based on your binding these setting might differ):

```
 <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

   </binding>
```

**--OR**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IManagementService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: tried this but no luck yet..<binding name="x" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"
useDefaultWebProxy="true"><readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
<security mode="Transport"> <transport clientCredentialType="None"/></security></binding>

Comment: Please make sure this binding is used in actual endpoint by setting `bindingConfiguration="x"`  like `<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="x" contract="Service.IService">`

Comment: i have following config. but no luck <service name="LTL.Appraisals.InboundService.LTLInboundServiceCoreLogicPCR" behaviorConfiguration="LTLInboundServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8741/LTLInboundService/" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour"
                  contract="LTL.Appraisals.InboundService.LTLInboundServiceCoreLogicPCR" name="webHttpBinding_LTLInboundService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>

Comment: Add above `bindingConfiguration` having increased value for attributes in Endpoint.

Comment: I am not sure i understand.. Here is more detail about this issue on this thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070330/webhttpbinding-having-issue-with-posting-1mb-xml-file

Comment: Please check the fix on other thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070330/webhttpbinding-having-issue-with-posting-1mb-xml-file thanks Tim and Pranav